# Econometrics/Statistics Regression Question

Tags: statistics, regression, linear-regression, regression-analysis, economics

[image]

As you can see from the provided picture given Heart attack given rate per 100,000 population. I was able to successfully ran my regression; but now I am trying to figure out how to alter my coefficients if heart attack rates were reported per 1000 populations. (I was given a hint saying that demonstrate this algebraically using the formulas for the OLS coefficients: (i) 0 ,(ii) 1 but couldn't figure out) any directives would greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You have $y_i = \beta_0 + x_i \beta_1 + \epsilon_i$ and we are replacing $x_i$ by $1000x_i$ to get $y_i = \beta_0' + (1000x_i) \beta_1' + \epsilon_i$. What would be nice is if the constant terms, $\beta_0$ and $\beta_0'$ are equal and also if the slopes $\beta_1$ and $1000\beta_1'$ are equal.

One way to show that this is what happens is to take the formulas:

$$\hat\beta_1 = \frac{\sum (x_i - \bar x)(y_i - \bar y)}{\sum (x_i - \bar x)^2}$$

What happens if you replace

$$x_i \gets 1000x_i \text{ and } \bar x \gets \frac1n\sum_{i=1}^n(1000x_i) = \frac{1000}{n}\sum_{i=1}^nx_i = 1000\bar x?$$

Then do the same for $\hat\beta_0 = \bar y - \bar x \hat \beta_1$.

Comment: ok, so what am I understanding from this is after doing all this proof; lets assume for the sake of the argument my Y(hat)=10+5Xi after this it will just be divide my coefficients by 1000. (Forgive my ignorance that is just what I am understanding after trying)

Comment: @mva So there is a difference between: doing this makes the equation work out and proving that that is optimal. If you divide the coefficient by 1000 the equation works out but that isn't proof that the new coefficient gives the least squares solution. Now there are multiple ways to prove this, but the simplest is to take the formula for the least squares solution and make the substitution there.

Comment: Thank you that makes sense. Appreciate the help

Comment: @mva I would suggest, that you accept the answer.